# Is it possible to download source files / code of create-react-app application?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, obfuscation

Is there a potential way to download somehow the source(or code) of my create-react-app application if I disable the map files?

Thanks

Comment: All obfuscation can be reverse engineered. Do not put any sensitive or secret information in your source files.

Comment: @mousetail I'm aware of that.

Comment: Seems like you know the answer already. Yes, you can find the source with various reverse engineering tools and a bit of effort. No, you can't just download it. Not even if you do include the map files.

Comment: @mousetail I'm aware of reverse-engineering, but I'm not fully sure about how react and create-react-app works. .map files makes it easy to download the source code of the app in a right structure, it's almost the same as the source files. Thanks for helping though, Maurits :)

Comment: Create-react-app does not do any special minification, it's really just a wrapper around webpack

Comment: You basically answered my question/concerns then. Thank you!